# How can I replace prefab with other prefab when it toches something? Unity / C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 1 prefab witch can run and when it touches some object it has to change to another prefab without reloading the scene is this possible? If yes then how?

Comment: One way is to create a parent for both of these prefabs, set the other one to inactive, and when it touches another object, set the first object to inactive and the second one to active

Comment: yes, but the second one has to spawn instead of first

Answer (score 0):

you have to take the position of your object when it touches another object and instantiate your prefab when it touches the other object

Answer (score 0):

When the first prefab touches something, you could instantiate the new prefab at the first ones location, and then destroy the original prefab, or set it inactive.